# Poedit Permission Denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, poedit

I installed poedit 3.3.1 on my Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to access the .po files found in the `var/www/html/` directory. However, every time I try, I get `Error opening directory '/var': Permission Denied`

I changed the ownership of the `var` directory and even ran `chmod 777` on it but the error persists. I am having to copy the files into the desktop every time, edit them, and then recopy them. Anyone knows how i can run poedit as an admin or fix this issue?

When trying to run `sudo poedit` I get the following error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
14:21:13: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

It seems there is some UID issue. When i manually created the directory, the first line of the error disappeared.

Running `poedit` without sudo opens normally without any errors or warnings.

Update: fixed the sudo issues `sudo poedit` now works but still have the permission issue.

Comment: Did you install poedit from Snap? Is there anything in `dmesg | grep /var`?

Comment: @user1686 yes i did use snap store to install it as recommended by their site, and inside `dmesg` I have the following: 
`audit: type=1400 audit(1685535500.577:992): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.poedit.poedit" name="/var/" pid=49276 comm="pool-net.poedit" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
`

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, just do not run graphical programs with `sudo` at all. If you need to edit something that you don't have permissions for, then it's better to grant yourself the permissions to access the file.

Unfortunately, in this case, it's the Snap system's AppArmor policy limiting the app to accessing only files within your home directory – the file permissions or ownership of /var are most likely not the problem – and although you *could* edit the AppArmor profile that Snap has installed for poedit, I'm not sure if there's a way to do it persistently. (I'll probably update the post someday, but it might have been already discussed on AskUbuntu.)

One alternative is to run the editor through the `sudoedit` tool instead – this does not 'sudo' the editor, but instead automates the copying of the file to an accessible location and back:

```
SUDO_EDITOR=poedit sudoedit /var/html/whatever.po
```

Alternatively, if the editor is GTK-based, specify an `admin://` URL to use GTK's built-in "admin access" feature:

```
poedit admin:///var/html/whatever.po
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately both solutions did not work. Even with the proper path it was not "finding" the .po file.